# How to disable Overlay in RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

If I write a text in one of the two fields, the last textViews are displayed over the button...

Thats bad.
I don't want it.
I'm searching for an prosibilty to disable that.
Maybe for example to hide the button if the keyboard is displayed
or make the text scrollable

donst worry abaut the grid, it gets in 9 rows TextViews

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
tools:context=".ActivityMain_plain" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button_berechnen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/Button_berechnen" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button_berechnen"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tV_input_snm_txt"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium" >

    <requestFocus android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</EditText>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_snm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_input_snm_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/input_snm"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/input_snm"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_input_ipAdresse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/input_ipAdresse"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/input_snm"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

</GridLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_Klasse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/table_gridLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/txt_Klasse" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsNetz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tV_Klasse"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/txt_BitsNetz" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsSubnetz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tV_BitsNetz_erg"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/txt_BitsSubnetz" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsHost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tV_BitsSubnetz"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/txt_BitsHost" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tV_BitsHost"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/txt_MagischeZahl" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlHost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tV_AnzahlSubnetz"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/txt_AnzHosts" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlSubnetz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/txt_AnzSubnetze" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_Klasse_erg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tV_Klasse"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tV_Klasse"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/input_snm"
    android:minWidth="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsNetz_erg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tV_BitsNetz"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tV_BitsNetz"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tV_Klasse_erg"
    android:minWidth="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsSubnetz_erg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tV_BitsSubnetz"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tV_Klasse_erg"
    android:minWidth="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsHost_erg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tV_BitsHost"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tV_BitsHost"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tV_BitsNetz_erg"
    android:minWidth="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl_erg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tV_BitsHost_erg"
    android:minWidth="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlSubnetz_erg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tV_AnzahlSubnetz"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tV_BitsHost_erg"
    android:minWidth="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlHost_erg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tV_AnzahlHost"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl_erg"
    android:minWidth="100dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know why, but no good way how to fix it...
I know with relative layouts overlays are possible, but here I don't want it...

Comment: Your questions is unclear. Do you mind updating it?

Comment: Not really. So you wish to make your view, inflated by the XML layout you're providing, scrollable?

Comment: I want a possibility to disable the overlay - maybe with a complete scrollable layout or with hiding the button (in java) or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this might solve your problem:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                tools:context=".ActivityMain_plain">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_berechnen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:text="@string/Button_berechnen"/>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button_berechnen"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tV_input_snm_txt"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium">

        <requestFocus android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    </EditText>


    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_snm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tV_input_snm_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/input_snm"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:text="@string/input_snm"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tV_input_ipAdresse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:text="@string/input_ipAdresse"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/Button_berechnen"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_snm">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridLayout
                    android:id="@+id/table_gridLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:columnCount="5"
                    android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

            </GridLayout>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_Klasse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:text="@string/txt_Klasse"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsNetz"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:text="@string/txt_BitsNetz"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsSubnetz"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:text="@string/txt_BitsSubnetz"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsHost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:text="@string/txt_BitsHost"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:text="@string/txt_MagischeZahl"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlHost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:text="@string/txt_AnzHosts"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlSubnetz"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:text="@string/txt_AnzSubnetze"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_Klasse_erg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsNetz_erg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsSubnetz_erg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_BitsHost_erg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl_erg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlSubnetz_erg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlHost_erg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I haven't actually tested the code, but the notion should be correct.

Also, I would strongly suggest you revisit your XML layout, as it could be improved.

Comment: what do you mean with revisit? what should I revisit precise?

Comment: Maybe I was too quick to judge. If it works for you, then that's fine. Does my solution solves your problem?

Comment: "invalid layout parameter token"

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Linear Layout: Warning: android:layout_alignParentLeft  android:layout_below

Comment: now I can scrolling :D - but the empty views are now below the text

Comment: If you want them to be below the grid, there's an easy fix - just set the ScrollView `layout_below` to grid id.

Comment: Please vote/accept my answer as a solution if it helped solve your problem.